# die with reference to an object that overloads bool

Tags: perl

I'm using [Data::FormValidator](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/Data-FormValidator-4.81/) to deal with some data validation in DBIx::Class (via [DBIx::Class::Validation](http://search.cpan.org/~claco/DBIx-Class-Validation-0.02005/)).  DBIC::Validation ultimately does `croak $results` if the validation fails, where `$results` is a [Data::FormValidator::Results](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/Data-FormValidator-4.81/lib/Data/FormValidator/Results.pm) object.  Unfortunately, that croak does not trigger my try/catch around the DBIC calls.

Digging around a bit, I made this simplified test case (excluding DBIC entirely):

```
use strict;
use Data::FormValidator;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
use TryCatch; #or Try::Tiny or eval, same results for each

#setup a profile and values that fail under that profile
my $input_profile = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   required => [ qw( good_ip bad_ip ) ],                                                                                                                                                                                           
   constraints => {                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     good_ip => 'ip_address',                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     bad_ip => 'ip_address',                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

my $validator = new Data::FormValidator({default => $input_profile});                                                                                                                                                                          

my $input_hashref = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   'good_ip' => '127.0.0.1',                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   'bad_ip'  => '300.23.1.1',                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    };
try {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    my $results = $validator->check($input_hashref,'default');                                                                                                                                                                                 
    die $results;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
} catch (Data::FormValidator::Results $e) {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    print STDERR "failed with ".scalar(@{$e->invalid('bad_ip')})." invalid\n";                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

I would expect that my catch block would get triggered.  Instead, nothing happens (execution continues).

Looking at the source of the Results object, I see that it overloads `bool` with it's `success` method.  Removing that fixes my issue, but I don't understand why.  If that's the whole problem, is there a good way to work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is a bug in TryCatch. `$results` stringifies to the empty string and TryCatch calls `if $@` when it should call `if defined $@`.

---

Here's an example without Data::FormValidator:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

package Foo;

use overload '""' => sub { '' };

sub new {
    bless {}, $_[0];
}

package main;

use TryCatch;

try {
    my $foo = Foo->new;
    die $foo;
}
catch($e) {
    say "<<<$e>>>";
}
```

TryCatch uses [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare) to inject custom code when the Perl lexer encounters certain keywords. In this case, it generates something like this:<sup>*</sup>

```
try;
{
    local $@;
    eval {
        my $foo = Foo->new;
        die $foo;
    };
    $TryCatch::Error = $@;
}

if ($TryCatch::Error) {
```

Since `$@` is the empty string, `if ($TryCatch::Error)` is false and the `catch` block is never entered.

This is a bug (one of [many](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=TryCatch) for TryCatch). Use `eval` or Try::Tiny instead (just remember to check for `defined`, not truthy/falsey).

---

* If you want to see exactly what gets injected, set the environment variable `TRYCATCH_DEBUG` to 1.

Comment: Yep, that seems to cover it, thanks.  I realize now that when I thought eval and try::tiny were failing, it was because of what you said - `defined($@)` vs  just `$@`